# how can i make the field looks mandatory using HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css, django

I want to make a field mandatory but the *required in red color is coming below the field name which i want just beside to field name

here is the HTML code

```html
<div class="span12" id="propertytype">
    {% for field1 in propertytypeform %}   
    <p>
        <label> {{ field1.label_tag }}
            {% if field1.field.required %}
            <span class="required-field">*Required</span>
            {% endif %}
        </label>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; {{ field1 }} <br />
        { field1.errors }}
    </p>
    {% endfor %}                            
</div>
```

CSS file

```css
.required-field{
    color:red;  
    font-size:8px;
    /*position:absolute;
    top:-50;*/
}
```

Comment: required tag is used in input filed in html for mandatory for above scenario u need to use javascript to check if ur field is empty then change the color to red.

Comment: i don't want to change the color they both are static field name and the *required word

Comment: Final HTML (i.e. without server-side scripting) is better for this kind of questions

Comment: Does `{{ field1.label_tag }}` render just the label text? if so adding `display: inline-block;` to the 'required-field' class should fix the layout issue.

Comment: can you please help me with the problem i have asked..i know its realted to CSS but still not able to figure out why these two are not coming in same line

Comment: jamie Read i tried it also but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="field">
  <div class="fieldname">UserName<span class="mandatory">*</span></div></div>
```

> Now you write the css code for class name mandatory

```
<style>
   .mandatory{color:red;}</style>
```

Comment: thanks but this is what i am doing the difference is.. here i am using django rest the syntax you have wriiten is exactly same as mine...it still not working..

Answer (score 0):

The render of : `{{ field1.label_tag }}` is made by a `<p>` tag. A `<p>` tag is a block tag in HTML so it take 100% of the width of the page. So there is no place next to the field `{{ field1.label_tag }}` and so it displays the rest on the next line.

It's only a CSS issue.

What you can do is :

```
<span class="field">{{ field1.label_tag }}</span>

.field p {
  width: 200px;
}
```

This is for the example but I recommand you to use `<div>` to adjust the width of `<p>`

Answer (score 0):

You can also use display:flex to get all the content in a same line inside a tag. So can you once use a following code I hope it will help you.

```
#propertytype p label {
    display: flex;
}
```

And if you want to learn more about flex property then visit [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp)